# How do you pass parameters by ref when calling a static method using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm calling a static method on an object using reflection:

```
MyType.GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, new object[] { Parameter1, Parameter2 });
```

How do you pass parameters by ref, rather that by value?  I assume they would be by value by default.  The first parameter ("Parameter1" in the array) should be by ref, but I can't figure out how to pass it that way.

Answer (score 17):

For a reference parameter (or out in C#), reflection will copy the new value into the object array at the same position as the original parameter.  You can access that value to see the changed reference.

```
public class Example {
  public static void Foo(ref string name) {
    name = "foo";
  }
  public static void Test() {
    var p = new object[1];
    var info = typeof(Example).GetMethod("Foo");
    info.Invoke(null, p);
    var returned = (string)(p[0]);  // will be "foo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `Type.GetMethod` and use the `BindingFlag` of just `BindingFlags.Static`, it won't find your method. Remove the flag or add `BindingFlags.Public` and it will find the static method.

```
public Test { public static void TestMethod(int num, ref string str) { } }

typeof(Test).GetMethod("TestMethod"); // works
typeof(Test).GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.Static); // doesn't work
typeof(Test).GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.Static
                                     | BindingFlags.Public); // works
```

Comment: You're right.  Thanks.  Not the source of my original problem, but still a problem.